# Keycloak with PHP - BASICS

Tags: php, keycloak, openid-connect

I want to use Keycloak as an identity provider (IdP) which secure access to my application written in PHP. Because Keycloak have no supported Client Adapters for PHP, I researched a litte bit. There are different ways to integrate the Relying Party (RP) into client application:

1. Keycloak have mod_auth_openidc. So this is a module for a Apache server as Relying Party. (It blocks the request before reaching the service )
2. Over things like [PHP Clients](https://oauth.net/code/php/) or Laravel --> [Authlete Laravel](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-php)

I am completely new to this area and prefer number 2,3. I have set up an Keycloak server and wrote a ServiceProviderInterface (SPI) for my User DB in the Keycloak server. This works fine and with Postman I am able to request the endpoints. Next step is to build an example PHP application to secure with Keycloak. Are there any basic step by step tutorials out there?

How do i authenticate my user against the IdP?
And how do I authorize later with the scopes and claims of Keycloak?
And are there any better tutorials out there?
I found [AUTHENTICATE KEYCLOAK ACCESS TOKEN IN LARAVEL](https://tliebrand.com/18-sicherheit/27-authenticate-keycloak-access-token-in-laravel), [Apereo CAS - Securing PHP with OpenID Connect](https://fawnoos.com/2020/12/22/cas63x-oidc-php-client/), [PHP OpenID Connect Basic Client](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP) but they did not really help me setting things up.

Comment: You will need some OIDC (not only OAuth) library for the Keycloak IDP. https://openid.net/developers/libraries/ is a good starting point. Keycloak doesn't have mod_auth_openidc - that's independent project based on OIDC protocol. And I would say there are better "auth" proxies - e.g. https://github.com/gogatekeeper/gatekeeper

Comment: Is there a way to validate ID token without calling the IdP again?

Comment: Absolutely, asymetric cryptography is used usually. So you just need a public realm key and you can verify any signature of the token.